# Asynctask getActivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-toolbar

I am trying to set my toolbar title from an async task. I am getting a cannot resolve method getActivity() in this line:

```
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
```

My code looks like this:

```
/**
 * Created by Mike on 2/28/15.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 4/26/14.
 */
public class GetBeerDataJSON2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    String id;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;


    public GetBeerDataJSON2 (Context context, String beerID)
    {
        c = context;
        id = beerID;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting beer information");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{

            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);

            //get beer details



            //todo: lets get things from our new JSON

            String name = o.getString("name");
            String beerDescription = o.getString("description");
            String abv = o.getString("abv");
            String ibu = o.getString("ibu");
            String image = o.getString("icon");
            String glass = o.getString("glass");
            String beerBreweryStyle = o.getString("style");
            String beerBreweryName = o.getString("brewery");
            String status = o.getString("status");
            String rating = o.getString("rating");
            String food = o.getString("food");




            int beerRate = 0;
            beerRate = o.getInt("userRating");



            //prepare buttons
            //Button buttonBrewery = (Button) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.buttonBrewery);
            //Button buttonStyle = (Button) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.buttonStyle);

            TextView tv_breweryName = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerBreweryName);
            TextView tv_styleName = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerStyleName);

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("styleName",beerBreweryStyle);
            editor.putString("beerName",name);
            editor.putString("lastBeer",name);
            editor.putString("breweryName",beerBreweryName);
            editor.putString("styleName",beerBreweryStyle);
            editor.commit();

            ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);


            //create text views
            TextView styleTitle = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerTitle);
            styleTitle.setText(name);

            TextView textABV = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.abv);
            textABV.setText(abv);

            TextView textIBU = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.IBU);
            textIBU.setText(ibu);

            TextView textGlass = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.glass);
            textGlass.setText(glass);

            TextView textDescription= (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerDescription);
            textDescription.setText(beerDescription);

            String breweryButton = "Brewery: ";
            String styleButton = "Style: ";

            //todo: add beer name to shared prefs

            tv_breweryName.setText(beerBreweryName);
            tv_styleName.setText(beerBreweryStyle);

            //get user id
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
            final String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

            //check if user has beer
            String url = "http://www.beerportfolio.com/app_checkBeer.php?";
            String userURLComp = "u=" + userID;
            final String beerID = "&b=" + id;

            url = url + userURLComp + beerID;
            //new CheckBeerJSON(c,id,userID).execute(url);

            //todo: add code for check beer here

            if(status.equals("no")){




                //clear loader image
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) (LinearLayout)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                ll.removeAllViews();

                //Add beer add button
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout addButton = (LinearLayout)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                addButton.addView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addbeerbutton_layout, null));

                //add on click listener here
                Button bt4 = (Button)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.button1);
                bt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // do whatever stuff you wanna do here



                        //get beer details
                        String url2 = "http://www.beerportfolio.com/app_addBeer.php?";
                        String urlUserID = "u=" + userID;
                        String urlBeerID = "&bID=" + id;


                        Log.d("url", id);
                        //construct url for adding beer
                        url2 = url2 + urlUserID + urlBeerID;



                        Log.d("url", url2);

                        //execute async on url to add to brewery
                        new AddBeer(c).execute(url2);

                        //to do: change to start rater
                        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                        ll.removeAllViews();

                        //add rater

                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)((Activity) c).getSystemService(((Activity) c).LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        LinearLayout addButton = (LinearLayout)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                        addButton.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addrate_layout, null));


                        //add listener to rate button todo
                        //add listener to bar
                        addListenerOnRatingBar(c);




                    }
                });


            }

            else{


                //clear loader image
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) (LinearLayout)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                ll.removeAllViews();

                //inflate star rater
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                LinearLayout addButton = (LinearLayout)((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                addButton.addView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addrate_layout, null));

                RatingBar r = (RatingBar) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerRatingBar);

                //get user data


                //get beer rating with async task and update rate bar
                String url2 = "http://www.beerportfolio.com/app_getRating.php?";
                String userURLComp2 = "u=" + userID;
                String beerID2 = "&b=" + beerID;

                url = url + userURLComp2 + beerID2;



                //new GetUserRating(c,r).execute(url2);
                r.setRating(beerRate);

                //add listener to bar
                addListenerOnRatingBar(c);



            }

            //end code here

            //todo: get rate code goes here


            TextView tv1 = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.beerRating);

            tv1.setText(rating + " / 5");

            //end rate code


            String url2 = "http://beerportfolio.com/app_beerDetails2.php?u="+ userID + "&b=" + beerID;
            //new GetBeerRateJSON(c,id).execute(url2);

            ImageView im1 = (ImageView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.image);
            if(image.equals("N/A")){
                //set image as png
                im1.setImageResource( R.drawable.noimage);
            }

            else{
                ImageDownloadTask imageD = new ImageDownloadTask(im1);
                imageD.execute(image);
            }


            //tdo: add food paring

            if (food.equals("N/A")){


            }




            Dialog.dismiss();







        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    private void addListenerOnRatingBar(Context view) {
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) ((Activity) view).findViewById(R.id.beerRatingBar);

        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {

                //next async task to update online database
                float stars = ratingBar.getRating();

                //get user details
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                //get beer id
                String beerID = id;

                //get rating
                String urlRate = "r=" + String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
                String urlUserID = "&u=" + userID;
                String urlBeerID = "&b=" + beerID;

                //construct url
                String url2 = "http://www.beerportfolio.com/app_rateUpdate.php?";

                url2 = url2 + urlRate + urlUserID + urlBeerID;


                //async task to update rating in database
                new UpdateRating(c).execute(url2);





            }
        });
    }

    public String getName(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getABV(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("abv");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getIBU(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("ibu");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getImage(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("labels").getString("large");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getGlass(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("glass").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getBreweryName(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("breweries").getJSONObject(0).getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getBreweryStyle(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("style").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }

    public String getDescription(JSONObject json){
        String holder;

        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }

        return holder;

    }




    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

I feel like I need to use the context c that I bring in, but every combination I have tried has failed me.

Comment: You need to use your context `c` instead of `getActivity();`

Comment: ((ActionBarActivity)c).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name); Since you are passing a context to that asynctask from your activity

Answer (score 1):

Use context:

```
((ActionBarActivity)context).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should do all time consuming operation in a `doInBackground` method. This also include parsing JSON data. In `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` method you should do only GUI things.

Don't use activity or activity context directly in `AsyncTask` class. Use listeners together with `WeakReference` to change GUI things. For example:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  public interface TaskListener {
    void onTitleReceived(String title);
  }

  private final WeakReference<TaskListener> mTaskListenerRef;    

  public MyAsyncTask(TaskListener listener) {
    this.mTaskListenerRef = new WeakReference<>(listener);
  }

  public void notifyTitleReceived(String title) {
    TaskListener listener = mTaskListenerRef.get();
    if (listener != null) {
      listener.onTitleReceived(title);
    }
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    ...
    notifyTitleReceived(newTitle);
    ...
  }
}

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MyAsyncTask.TaskListener {
    @Override
    public void onTitleReceived(String title) {
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    private void runTask() {
      new MyTask(this).execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define an static instance of actvity , set it before `excute()`

in your GetBeerDataJSON2 class

```
public static ActionBarActivity instance = null;
```

in your ActionBarActivity class :

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle){
GetBeerDataJSON2 task = new GetBeerDataJSON2() ; 
task.instance = this;
task.excute();
}
```

another solotion is passing `this` as the `context`in your constructor of `GetBeerDataJSON2` and cast it to `ActionBarActivity`

anyway better way of doing this is using libraries like volley to get json rather than building the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers in constructor while creating instance of GetBeerDataJSON2(Context, Stirng) in Activity code  pass 'this' as first argument.

And cast it as :

```
((ActionBarActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
```

Instead of :

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
```

Error Because there is no method getActivity() defined for AsynchTask.