# How do I go about applying data I get from doInBackground() to apply to my RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, java-threads

I have viewed over 50 pages to find solution for my extremely simple app, but none seems to work for me. Please help.

Problem: I have a refresh button in the menu in MainActivity. When this is pressed, I want to execute my AsyncTask, then update ALL items in my RecyclerView.

Situation.

1. My app fetches data from API by OpenWeatherMap.org, then displays the data.
2. I have a MainActivity class (And my recyclerView resides in here.)
3. For recyclerView, I'm using RecyclerView.Adapter with GridViewManager.
4. I have a separate AsyncTask class.

So, what I have tried and did not work:

Method 1. Normal way. When refresh button selected, call my AsyncTask. In my PostExecute(), I am calling setter in the MainActivity

```
public void setWeatherData(String[] weatherData) {this.weatherData = weatherData;}
```

to assign the result array from doInBackGround method.

Then in MainActivity,

```
myAsyncTask.execute("43017,us");
recyclerView.recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But this causes `notifyDataSetChanged();` to be called BEFORE member vairable array in MainActivity is updated from `onPostExecute()`.

Method 2. Trying to update UI entirely from `onPostExecute` method in `MyAsyncTask.class`.

Well I know `onPostExecute`, even when it is written in different class, runs on the UI thread. So within the method, I did something like

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
RecyclerView recyclerView = mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In this method, with logging, I've confirmed that `onPostExecute` successfully updates the member variable in the MainActivity, it's just that `notifyDataSetChanged` gets called TOO early, specifically before `onPostExecute` is complete in the background.

I hope to get an answer for this and was clear enough about my situation. I will post my MainActivity, Adapter and AsyncTask codes down below.

MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String weatherData[] = {
        "Today - Sunny",
            "Tomorrow - Cloudy",
            "Tuesday - Rainy",
            "Wednesday - Sunny",
            "Thursday - Sunny",
            "Friday - Sunny",
            "Saturday - Cloudy",
            "Sunday - Rainy :/"
    };

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private mAdapter adapter;
    private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 1;
    private MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    private Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_weatherData);
        setLayout(getApplicationContext());
        adapter = new mAdapter(weatherData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Log.v("Menu", "Refresh button selected.");
                //for now, take some random ZIP code
                myAsyncTask.execute("43017,us");
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.refreshContents(weatherData);
                for (int i = 0; i<weatherData.length; i++) {
                    Log.v("Refresh button", weatherData[i].toString());
                }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setLayout(Context context) {
        int scrollPosition = 0;
        //make a GridLayoutManager with 2 columns
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

        //set the mLayoutManager to the one that I just created
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, SPAN_COUNT));

        //set the offset decoration definition to my layout
        int middle_spacing = 30;
        boolean includeEdge = true;
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(SPAN_COUNT, middle_spacing, includeEdge));
    }

    public void setWeatherData(String[] weatherData) {
        this.weatherData = weatherData;
    }
    public String[] getWeatherData() { return weatherData; }
}
```

MyAsyncTask.java:

```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

    public final static String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = "bc607b72747aa672bf2ac9a5f3a5fc84";
    String forecastJsonStr = null;

    private String format = "json";
    private String units = "metric";
    private int numDays = 7;
    private String data[] =null;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (params.length == 0) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "No parameter is taken.");
            return null;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            //put the buffer in String var forecastJsonStr
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            Log.v("AsyncTask", forecastJsonStr.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Async", "Reader is null, something wrong.");
                }
            }
        }
        //Then put the string contents into an array
        try {
            ParseWeatherData parser = new ParseWeatherData();
            data = parser.getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            return data;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String data[]) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);

        if (data != null) {
            //this log works fine: the fetched data is successfully stored...
            for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                Log.v("onPostExecute", data[i].toString());
            }
            //how do I pass this data to the main thread?

            mainActivity = new MainActivity();
            mainActivity.setWeatherData(data);
        }



    }
}
```

Finally, mAdapter.java:

```
    public class mAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<mAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String data[];

    public mAdapter(String data[]) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View listView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(listView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.weather.setText(data[position]);
        Log.v("BindView", "Item " + position + " set.");
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (data == null) {
            Log.v("WeatherAdapter", "Oops, getting null in the adapter.");
            return 0;
        } else {
            return data.length;
        }
    }

    public void refreshContents(String data[]) {
        this.data = null;
        this.data = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView weather, day;

        //currently ViewHolder is set as the TextView for logging
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            weather = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_text);

            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: write down interface for call back  and pass your result in onPostexecute()
and in main activity receive data

Answer (score 0):

First don't create new object of MainActivity in MyAsyncTask. Actually what's happening is AsyncTask runs on a new Thread so when you do

```
myAsyncTask.execute("43017,us");
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.refreshContents(weatherData);
```

then `myAsyncTask` runs in a different thread and the next lines start executing right before `.execute` without waiting for `asynctask` to finish and even if it waits for the `asynctask` to finish, creating a new object to update the data in `MainActivity` is not gonna work. So what you can do to update your list from `onPostExecute` method is pass your Activity to `myAsyncTask` from parameters. Don't initialize your `myAsyncTask` in the beginning, just remove the  `= new MyAsyncTask()` from `private MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();` in `MainActivity` and now replace the lines in MainActivity with this:

**Instead of this in your MainActivity**

```
myAsyncTask.execute("43017,us");
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.refreshContents(weatherData);
for (int i = 0; i<weatherData.length; i++) {
    Log.v("Refresh button", weatherData[i].toString());
}
```

**Write this**

```
myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
myAsyncTask.execute("43017,us");
```

and to refresh the contents you can make your `adapter` public so that you could call `notifydatasetchanged` from myAsyncTask itself but if you want to follow your code written after `.execute` then you can move it to a new method something like below

```
public void refreshList(){
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.refreshContents(weatherData);
    for (int i = 0; i<weatherData.length; i++) {
        Log.v("Refresh button", weatherData[i].toString());
    }
}
```

and now what's left is getting context of your `MainActivity` in `MyAsyncTask` and refreshing your list in `onPostExecute`. So make changes like following:

**Create a constructor of your MyAsyncTask**

```
 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {
     MainActivity mainActivity;
     public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity mainActivity){
         this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
     }
```

**Replace this in MyAsyncTask**

```
mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.setWeatherData(data);
```

**With this**

```
mainActivity.setWeatherData(data);
mainActivity.refreshList();
```

I din't tested it myself but i think this should solve your problem. You can try debugging this and see how it is working. And if you face any problems please comment down below.

**Edit**

Based on the comment by **@Ganesh Patil** you can create an interface for this solution as well. For the reference of using interface in AsyncTask you can follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958913/7071039

But to keep it simple i didn't used `interface` and just passed the context of `MainActivity` in the `MyAsyncTask`

**Editing based on the comment**

> Dear PC HUB, firstly thank you so much for your very detailed answer.
>   All of your explanations made sense and I applied the codes. My app
>   now doesn't crash and all the data is properly passed / retrieved but
>   somehow mainActivity.refreshList() and
>   recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() is still not working.
>   Hence, my recyclerView still doesn't change the contents at all... I
>   am not sure of what to do. – Rikuto Echigoya

change your refreshList into this

```
public void refreshList(){
    /* Check your Weather Data size in this method to find out weather your data is changing or not */
    Log.d("Tag","SIZE OF WEATHER DATA : "+weatherData.length);
    /* You already have the adapter object so you don't need to 
      get it using recyclerview.getAdapter. Just do it directly like this */
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Not changing this as this will not stop your list from refreshing :P
    for (int i = 0; i<weatherData.length; i++) {
        Log.v("Refresh button", weatherData[i].toString());
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you've called `mainActivity.setWeatherData(data);` before `mainActivity.refreshList();` in your `MyAsyncTask`.

If it still doesn't solve your problem then share your updated code so that we could see why your list is not getting updated :)

Comment: Dear PC HUB, firstly thank you so much for your very detailed answer. All of your explanations made sense and I applied the codes. My app now doesn't crash and all the data is properly passed / retrieved but somehow `mainActivity.refreshList()` and `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` is still not working. Hence, my recyclerView still doesn't change the contents at all... I am not sure of what to do.

Comment: please check the updated code...and let me know if it still doesn't solve your problem. Do some debugging and if you can't solve it then just share your code so that i could see where the mistake is ^_^

Comment: THANK YOU! Well like you mentioned, I ended up passing MainActivity to the adapter and it worked. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped you...please upvote the answer ^_^